# What is the format of objects in V8 Javascript VM?

Tags: javascript, virtual-machine, low-level

I'm interested in the low-level implementation details of V8 objects, both in 32- and 64-bit VMs. Specially I'd like to get as much as information as possible about object header bits and pointer tagging.

Links to blog posts and slides are welcome.

Comment: Your question is so broad, that the best answer would probably be to refer to the repository: https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git